# Chrome DevTools API

Tags: google-chrome

I was reading up on chromedriver, trying to figure out how it controls Chrome when I came across its official documentation. According to the documentation, chromedriver uses the Runtime.evaluate command to send chrome Javascript files to execute.

My question -- cause I couldn't find any information on it online -- is, what is this Runtime.evaluate command, and is it a part of some API for chrome. If it is part of some API for chrome, how do I access the command directly from Powershell.